# How to get R Help tab to automatically open on the right side in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, r

As the title suggest, I am trying to get the "R Help" tab that pops up to consistently open in a panel on the right side in VS Code.
Essentially, when I want info on a function, I will typically type `> ?function` in my R terminal, and a "R Help" tab will open. However, I want the tab to be kept separate from my open scripts, notebooks etc., similar to RStudio

I've tried to "split right" an open R Help tab, and pin it there. If I look up another function, inconsistently open in the right side tab I created or it will revert and close the right side panel and open up the R Help tab on the left side with my other tabs.

Is there a way to keep R Help to open consistently in a right side panel?